# Activity not found exception: unable to find actitvity class

Tags: android, xml, exception

In following code shown below
I am trying open a new activity(memo.class to view.class) when click view button.but showing an error "activity not found exception: unable to find explicit activity class".
what is wrong in my code??
please help me

my code:

memo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:text="Titile" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<EditText android:id="@+id/question" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=""></EditText>
<TextView android:text="Text" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<EditText android:minLines="6" android:maxLines="10" android:id="@+id/answer" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=""></EditText>
<TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow>
<Button android:id="@+id/add" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="ADD" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/view" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="VIEW" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

memo.java

```
package quesansw.the1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Memo extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(this);
        Window window = d1.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

        d1.setTitle("Register Questions");

        d1.setContentView(R.layout.memo);
        d1.show();

        Button view1 = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.view);
        Button add = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.add);


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                EditText add = (EditText) d1.findViewById(R.id.question);
                EditText view = (EditText) d1.findViewById(R.id.answer);
                System.out.println(add.getText());
                System.out.println(view.getText());


            }
          });

        view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), View.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
}
}
```

view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<EditText android:id="@+id/question" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=""></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

view.java

```
package quesansw.the1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class View extends Activity { 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(this);
        Window window = d1.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

        d1.setTitle("Login");

        d1.setContentView(R.layout.view);

        d1.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: you might consider naming your activity subclass something other than `View`

Comment: @Kgrover Sure, I appreciate that. I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: @Tyler M. : I would like to know why cant you name a class "View" (I know View is a class of android and all)  But when i googled it, i couldnt find a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the Activity in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.yourpackagename.View"/>
```

Basically, your AndroidManifest.xml file (found in the root package folder) acts as a "settings" or "main controller" for your entire application, and so the system needs to be aware of each activity (essentially a page) that you will transition to or use.

Here are other things that can go within the [Activity tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) in the Manifest file.

Side Note: as @Tyler M. says, you should use another name than "View" for your Activity.

Comment: Try doing as @Tyler M. says and renaming the activity.

Comment: I would appreciate if you upvoted my answer, but I'm not sure if I directly want you to Accept my answer. It was @Tyler M's quick eye and I noticed the problem later. I will encourage him to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `Activity` subclass to something other than `View`.

It is generally a bad idea to use names of existing classes - it is a reference disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to include it in the Manifest.xml